# Cannot implicitly convert type string to `UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial in youtube to make a game in Unity

here is the link to the video it will start where he write this code [Link](https://youtu.be/uJl2YYiI-uM?t=516)

Its just text that appear and disappear when i enter a different room
the OnTriggerEnter2D call StartCoroutine if needText

screenshot
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bfv.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RoomMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 cameraChange;
    public Vector3 playerChange;
    private CameraMovment cam;
    public bool needText;
    public GameObject text;
    public Text placeText;
    public string placeName;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraMovment>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            cam.minPosition += cameraChange;
            cam.maxPosition += cameraChange;
            collision.transform.position += playerChange;

            if(needText)
            {
                StartCoroutine(placeNameCo);
            }
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator placeNameCo()
    {
        text.SetActive(true);
        placeText = placeName;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
        text.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

i get 2 errors:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'  Assembly-CSharp 

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'    Assembly-CSharp
```

Comment: Should be `StartCoroutine(placeNameCo())` and `placeText.text = placeName;`

Comment: Or StartCoroutine("placeNameCo") - one or the other.. and yes, placeText needs a .Text on the end.

Comment: This is [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`placeText` is the whole [Text Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html), so you want to assign your string to its `text` [property](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html) like:

`placeText.text = placeName;`

---

Also, [StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) needs either a routine in parameter or a string. So replace your line 38 by :

`StartCoroutine(placeNameCo())` or `StartCoroutine("placeNameCo")`

The first one is prefered because the string version has a higher runtime overhead to start the coroutine and you can pass only one parameter.